# Exercise $4(b)$, Ch. $2$, Rudin's RCA: why is $\mu(N) < 1/n$ for every $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The notation is borrowed from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (in particular, the proof of Riesz Representation Theorem).

> **Exercise $4(b)$, Chapter 2, Rudin** *(Real and Complex Analysis):* Examine the proof of the Riesz theorem and prove the following statement:
> If $E \in \mathfrak M_F$, then $E = N \cup K_1 \cup K_2 \cup \ldots$, where $K_i$ is a disjoint countable collection of compact sets and $\mu(N) = 0$.

> **Proof:** Now pick $E ∈ \mathfrak M_F$, and set $E_0 = E$. By Step V of the proof of the Riesz theorem, there is a compact set $K_1$ and an open set $V_1$ such that $K_1 ⊂ E_0 ⊂ V_1$ and $\mu(V_1\setminus K_1) < 1$. Then $E_0 \setminus K_1 ∈ \mathfrak M_F$ by Step VI, so set $E_1 = E_0 \setminus K_1$. Inductively, we can find a compact set $K_n$ and open set $V_n$ such that $K_n ⊂ E_{n−1} ⊂ V_n$ and $\mu(V_n \setminus K_n) < 1/n$, and define $E_n = E_{n−1}\setminus K_n$. Then set $N = E \setminus \bigcup_{n≥1} K_n$. Then $\mu(N) < 1/n$ for all $n$, so $\mu(N) = 0$, and the result follows.

**Question:** In the last step, how do we get $\mu(N) < 1/n$ for all $n$?

*My thoughts:* $\mu(V_n \setminus K_n) < 1/n$ gives us $\mu(E_{n-1} \setminus K_n) < 1/n$ since $E_{n-1}\subset V_n$ would imply $E_{n-1}\setminus K_n \subset V_n\setminus K_n$. $\mu(E_{n-1} \setminus K_n) < 1/n$ follows by monotonicity. I also noticed that $E = E_0 \supseteq E_1 \supseteq E_2 \ldots$ but I'm unable to use these facts to answer my question.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $E \subseteq E_{n} \cup K_1 \cup \cdots \cup K_n.$ Hence $N \subseteq E_n$ for each $n,$ now use the work you included to finish.

Comment: $N \subseteq E_n$ for every $n$ gives $\mu(N) \le \mu(E_n)$. What next?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor $\mu(E_n) = \mu(E_{n-1}\setminus K_n) \leq \mu(V_n \setminus K_n) < 1/n.$